# Python - exception's reason in classes

Tags: python, oop, exception

I learn object-oriented programming in python 3. I've some exception, for example:

```
try:
    self.result = (...)
except urllib.error.URLError as error:
    print(error)
```

Generally all variables in classes are prefixed with *self*. Adding *self* before *error* variable:

```
try:
    self.result = (...)
except urllib.error.URLError as self.error:
    print(self.error)
```

causes:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Shall I just skip *self* before variables containing reason of exception?

Comment: '*Generally all variables in classes are prefixed with self.*' is a comment that shows a massive lack of understanding - you should read up on what ``self`` is before trying to use it - understanding the concepts will make everything a lot easier, and it's not a hard thing once you understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`error` is the name you gave the exception. It is not a member of your class and thus is not prefixed with `self`.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the [documented grammar for the `try` compound statement](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) doesn't disallow using `self.error` as a target (the [`target` token](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target) includes attribute references). However, *because the target is to be cleared* when the `except` suite completes, only a local identifier is allowed, really. This is probably a bug in the documentation..